# Как в регистр FPU записать значение локальной переменной?

Tags: ассемблер

В регистре EAX лежит значение 5.0 и требуется через локальную переменную передать это значение в регистр FPU. Значения других регистров кроме EAX должно сохраниться

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может подойдет что-то вроде

```
push eax
fild dword ptr [esp]
```

Значение, созраненное в стеке условно можно считать "локальной переменной".

Либо вариант сохранения из EAX в ячейке памяти с последующей загрузкой в FPU:

```
mov dword ptr y, eax
fild dword ptr y
```

Здесь y - это локальная переменная.

Comment: В первом варианте нужно еще не забыть стэк выровнять (например с помощью `pop`).